# django - combine the output of json views

Tags: python, json, django, api, view

I write a simple json api, I use one base class, and I mostly write one api view per one model class. What I want is to combine the output of few views into one url endpoint, with as least as possible additional code.

code:

```
# base class
class JsonView(View):
   def get(self, request):
        return JsonResponse(self.get_json())
   def get_json(self):
        return {}

class DerivedView(JsonView):
   param = None
   def get_json(self):
      # .. use param..
      return {'data': []}
```

**urls.py:**

```
url('/endpoint1', DerivedView.as_view(param=1))
url('/endpoint2', DerivedView2.as_view())

# What I want:
url('/combined', combine_json_views({
   'output1': DerivedView.as_view(param=1),
   'output2': DerivedView2.as_view()
}))
```

So `/combined` would give me the following json response:

```
{'output1': {'data': []}, 'output2': output of DerivedView2}
```

This is how combine_json_views could be implemented:

```
def combine_json_views(views_dict):
   d = {}
   for key, view in views_dict.items():
      d[key] = view()  # The problem is here
   return json.dumps(d)
```

The problem is that calling `view()` give me the encoded json, so calling json.dumps again gives invalid json. I could call `json.loads(view())`, but that looks bad to decode the json that I just encoded.

How can I modify the code (maybe a better base class) here, while keeping it elegant and short? without adding too much code. Is there any way to access the data (dict) which is used to construct `JsonResponse`?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a combined view that calls the `get_json()` methods and combines them:

```
class CombinedView(JsonView):
  def get_json(self):
    view1 = DerivedView(param=1)
    view2 = DerivedView2()

    d = view1.get_json()
    d.update(view2.get_json())
    return d
```

then:

```
url('/combined', CombinedView.as_view()),
```

Comment: That helped me, I didn't know I can call a View class like a normal object. I mean, to use the constructor. I thought only as_view() is the way to use a class based view. So I've managed to write it like you suggested. Thanks

Comment: EDIT: what if I need the request in get_json() method? view1.get_json() won't work in this case

Comment: I believe you can specify the method as `def get_json(self,request)` to get the request object. You'd have to do it on all the views - Base, Derived 1&2 and Combined.

Comment: Could I do it with objects and not jsons?